# Não consigo arrumar linhas da tabela

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

Criei toda uma estilização para a tabela fiz tudo na primeira linha da tabela ficou ok, mas quando fui duplicar essa linha notei que só na primeira ficou a estilização, estou começando na área, se alguém poder dar uma ajuda, agradeço!

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-
BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" 
crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-
theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-
rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" 
crossorigin="anonymous">


<body>
<style>    
.table thead tr th {
    text-align: center;
}    
.table tbody tr td{
    text-align: center;            
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.table tbody tr td.end{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px !important;        
  }            

</style>

<div class="container">

    <div class="col-md-10">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered ">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Cliente</th>
                    <th>Localidade Cliente</th>
                    <th>Cidade/UF</th>
                    <th>Endereço</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>            

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ativo</td>
                    <td >Fulano de tal</td>
                    <td>Uberlandia</td>
                    <td >Uberlandia GO</td>
                    <td class="end">    
                            <div class="end_text">
                                É um fato conhecido de todos que um leitor 
se distrairá com o conteúdo de texto legível de uma página quando estiver 
examinando sua diagramação. A vantagem de usar Lorem Ipsum é que ele tem uma 
distribuição normal de letras, ao contrário de "Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo 
aqui", fazendo com que ele tenha uma aparência similar a de um texto 
legível. Muitos softwares de publicação e editores de páginas na internet 
agora usam Lorem Ipsum como texto-modelo padrão, e uma rápida busca por ' 
lorem ipsum' mostra vários websites ainda em sua fase de construção. Várias 
versões novas surgiram ao longo dos anos, eventualmente por acidente, e às 
vezes de propósito (injetando humor, e coisas do gênero).                                    
                            </div>

                            <div class="icone" style="position: 
absolute;left: 250px; top: 50px; display: none; cursor: pointer;">
                                <i onclick="fechareabrir()" class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>    
                            </div>    
                            <div class="icone2" style="position: 
absolute;left: 250px; bottom: 5px; display: none; cursor: pointer;">
                                <i onclick="fechareabrir()" class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-chevron-up"></i>    
                            </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Ativo</td>
                    <td >Fulano de tal</td>
                    <td>Uberlandia</td>
                    <td >Uberlandia GO</td>
                    <td class="end">    
                            <div class="end_text">
                                É um fato conhecido de todos que um leitor 
se distrairá com o conteúdo de texto legível de uma página quando estiver 
examinando sua diagramação. A vantagem de usar Lorem Ipsum é que ele tem uma 
distribuição normal de letras, ao contrário de "Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo 
aqui", fazendo com que ele tenha uma aparência similar a de um texto 
legível. Muitos softwares de publicação e editores de páginas na internet 
agora usam Lorem Ipsum como texto-modelo padrão, e uma rápida busca por 
'lorem ipsum' mostra vários websites ainda em sua fase de construção. Várias 
versões novas surgiram ao longo dos anos, eventualmente por acidente, e às 
vezes de propósito (injetando humor, e coisas do gênero).                                    
                            </div>

                            <div class="icone" style="position: 
absolute;left: 250px; top: 50px; display: none; cursor: pointer;">
                                <i onclick="fechareabrir()" class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>    
                            </div>    
                            <div class="icone2" style="position: 
absolute;left: 250px; bottom: 5px; display: none; cursor: pointer;">
                                <i onclick="fechareabrir()" class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-chevron-up"></i>    
                            </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>    


    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">    

    var end = document.querySelector('.end_text').textContent;            
    var fechado = true;        

    if(end.length > 120){        
        var end_novo = end.substring(0,120);        
         document.querySelector('.end_text').innerHTML = end_novo;
         document.querySelector('.icone').style.display = "block";
     }

    function fechareabrir(){
        if(fechado){
            abrir();
        }else{
            fechar();
        }
    }

    function abrir(){
        document.querySelector('.end_text').innerHTML = end;
        document.querySelector('.icone').style.display = "none";            
        document.querySelector('.icone2').style.display = "block";
        fechado = false;        
    }

    function fechar(){        
            var end_novo = end.substring(0,120);        
            document.querySelector('.end_text').innerHTML = end_novo;
            document.querySelector('.icone').style.display = "block";
            document.querySelector('.icone2').style.display = "none";
            fechado = true;        
    }


</script>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-
Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A segunda linha não está ficando com a setinha?

Comment: não mostra o icone e também não chama a função da substring

Comment: Não usa jQuery?

Comment: Bem complicado seu código. Dá pra fazer com JavaScript puro, embora seja mais complicado, mas com jQuery simplificaria bastante. De qualquer forma, acho que iria precisar reformular toda essa estrutura de funções.

Comment: tentei fazer com javascript o mais simples possível até porque estou iniciando nisso, a primeira linha da coluna fica tudo certo só da erro nas outras quando duplico

Comment: Sim, é porque cada elemento e classe tem um index.

Comment: hum então como faço para poder botar nas linhass que irão surgir?

Comment: Primeira coisa é usar jQuery, vai facilitar 90% o trabalho de reescrever seu código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tinha um comportamento inesperado na linha `document.querySelector('.end_text').innerHTML = end_novo;` pois esse comando retorna apenas o [primeiro elemento que corresponde](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp) ao seletor procurado (no caso a primeira linha da tabela). Para fazer o que você quer (aplicar alguns estilos com javascript a todas as linhas) é necessario usar a função [querySelectorAll](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp) que como esperado retorna todos os elementos que batem com o seletor procurado (e pode ser percorrida com um laço for).

Continuando para a solução. Tomei a liberdade de modificar um pouco a sua logica. Em vez de pegar as 120 primeiras letras da `<div class="end_text">` e substituir dentro da propria div (remover o conteudo anterior e colocar apenas as 120 primeiras letras), criei uma nova div chamada resumo, e nela foi colocada as 120 letras (sem mexer no conteudo da `<div class="end_text">`). A sua `<td class="end">` ficou assim:

```
<td class="end">    
    <div class="end_text">
        É um fato conhecido de todos que um leitor 
        se distrairá com o conteúdo de texto legível de uma página quando estiver 
        examinando sua diagramação. A vantagem de usar Lorem Ipsum é que ele tem uma 
        distribuição normal de letras, ao contrário de "Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo 
        aqui", fazendo com que ele tenha uma aparência similar a de um texto 
        legível. Muitos softwares de publicação e editores de páginas na internet 
        agora usam Lorem Ipsum como texto-modelo padrão, e uma rápida busca por ' 
        lorem ipsum' mostra vários websites ainda em sua fase de construção. Várias 
        versões novas surgiram ao longo dos anos, eventualmente por acidente, e às 
        vezes de propósito (injetando humor, e coisas do gênero).                                    
    </div>
    <div class="resumo">
    </div>
    <div class="icone" style="position: absolute;left: 250px; top: 50px; display: none; cursor: pointer;">
        <i onclick="fechareabrir(this)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>    
    </div>    
    <div class="icone2" style="position: absolute;left: 250px; bottom: 5px; display: none; cursor: pointer;">
        <i onclick="fechareabrir(this)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i>    
    </div>
</td>
```

A div resumo foi adicionada para evitar ter que armazenar com o javascript o conteudo antigo da div end_text. Alem disso a chamada a função `fechareabrir(this)` utiliza o parametro this (faz referencia ao objeto clicado. Permitindo identificar qual linha terá o conteudo expandido. Pois, usando a variavel fechado (como você começou) seria dificil diferenciar a linha que foi clicada. Já com o this ele identifica o objeto clicado, ou melhor, nesse caso o elemento que chama a função `fecharabrir()`). O JavaScript para preencher a div resumo e ocultar a div end_text é o seguinte (poucas alterações em relação ao seu!):

```
//retorna todos os elementos com a classe .end_text
    var ends = document.querySelectorAll('.end_text');            

    var end = 0;        

    for(var i = 0; i < ends.length; i++){
        //pega o conteudo de cada div com a classe .end_text
        end = ends[i].textContent;

        if(end.length > 120){        
            var end_novo = end.substring(0,120);        

            ends[i].parentElement.querySelector('.icone').style.display = "block";
            //oculta a div com a classe .end_text
            ends[i].style.display = "none";
            //coloca parte do texto da div com a classe .end_text na div resumo
            ends[i].parentElement.querySelector('.resumo').innerHTML = end_novo;
            ends[i].parentElement.querySelector('.resumo').style.display = "block";
        }
    }
```

A principal mudança em relação ao seu codigo foi o uso da propriedade `parentElement` usada para retornar o [pai de um elemento](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_parentelement.asp) (imediatamente acima no DOM).

As funções `fecharabrir`, `abrir` e `fechar` sofreram algumas alterações (comentadas no codigo):

```
function fechareabrir(elemento){
        //a variavel this representa o item clicado (argumento de fecharabrir). 
        //E tambem não é necessario alterar o conteudo da div .end_text
        //é complicado controlar o estado de varias linhas com 
        //a variavel fechado, é melhor checar o display da div resumo

        //a variavel elemento representa o elemento clicado
        //então devemos subir (acessar elementos pais) até chegar na div .end_text
        //após isso a variável elemento representa a td que possui .end_text, .resumo, .icone
        elemento = elemento.parentElement.parentElement;
        if(elemento.parentElement.querySelector(".resumo").style.display == "block"){
            abrir(elemento);
        }else{
            fechar(elemento);
        }
    }

    function abrir(elemento){

        //volta a exibir a div .end_text
        elemento.querySelector(".end_text").style.display = "block";
        //oculta a div .resumo
        elemento.querySelector(".resumo").style.display = "none";
        elemento.querySelector('.icone').style.display = "none";            
        elemento.querySelector('.icone2').style.display = "block";

    }

    function fechar(elemento){        
        //volta a exibir a div .resumo
        elemento.querySelector(".resumo").style.display = "block";

        //oculta a div .end_text
        elemento.querySelector(".end_text").style.display = "none";

        elemento.querySelector('.icone').style.display = "block";            
        elemento.querySelector('.icone2').style.display = "none";        
    }
```

Abaixo o codigo completo:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-
BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" 
crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-
theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-
rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" 
crossorigin="anonymous">


<body>
<style>    
.table thead tr th {
    text-align: center;
}    
.table tbody tr td{
    text-align: center;            
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.table tbody tr td.end{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px !important;        
  }            

</style>

<div class="container">

    <div class="col-md-10">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered ">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Cliente</th>
                    <th>Localidade Cliente</th>
                    <th>Cidade/UF</th>
                    <th>Endereço</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>            

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ativo</td>
                    <td >Fulano de tal</td>
                    <td>Uberlandia</td>
                    <td >Uberlandia GO</td>
                    <td class="end">    
                    <div class="end_text">
                                É um fato conhecido de todos que um leitor 
se distrairá com o conteúdo de texto legível de uma página quando estiver 
examinando sua diagramação. A vantagem de usar Lorem Ipsum é que ele tem uma 
distribuição normal de letras, ao contrário de "Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo 
aqui", fazendo com que ele tenha uma aparência similar a de um texto 
legível. Muitos softwares de publicação e editores de páginas na internet 
agora usam Lorem Ipsum como texto-modelo padrão, e uma rápida busca por ' 
lorem ipsum' mostra vários websites ainda em sua fase de construção. Várias 
versões novas surgiram ao longo dos anos, eventualmente por acidente, e às 
vezes de propósito (injetando humor, e coisas do gênero).                                    
                            </div>
                            <div class="resumo">
</div>
                            <div class="icone" style="position: 
absolute;left: 250px; top: 50px; display: none; cursor: pointer;">

                                <i onclick="fechareabrir(this)" class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>    
                            </div>    
                            <div class="icone2" style="position: 
absolute;left: 250px; bottom: 5px; display: none; cursor: pointer;">

                                <i onclick="fechareabrir(this)" class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-chevron-up"></i>    
                            </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Ativo</td>
                    <td >Fulano de tal</td>
                    <td>Uberlandia</td>
                    <td >Uberlandia GO</td>
                    <td class="end">    
                    <div class="end_text">
                    É um fato conhecido de todos que um leitor 
                    se distrairá com o conteúdo de texto legível de uma página quando 
                    estiver examinando sua diagramação. A vantagem de usar Lorem Ipsum é 
                    que ele tem uma 
                    distribuição normal de letras, ao contrário de "Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo 
                    aqui", fazendo com que ele tenha uma aparência similar a de um texto 
                    legível. Muitos softwares de publicação e editores de páginas na internet 
                    agora usam Lorem Ipsum como texto-modelo padrão, e uma rápida busca por 
                    'lorem ipsum' mostra vários websites ainda em sua fase de construção. Várias 
                    versões novas surgiram ao longo dos anos, eventualmente por acidente, e às 
                    vezes de propósito (injetando humor, e coisas do gênero).                                    
                            </div>
                            <div class="resumo">
                            </div>
                            <div class="icone" style="position: 
absolute;left: 250px; top: 50px; display: none; cursor: pointer;">

                                <i onclick="fechareabrir(this)" class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>    
                            </div>    
                            <div class="icone2" style="position: 
absolute;left: 250px; bottom: 5px; display: none; cursor: pointer;">

                                <i onclick="fechareabrir(this)" class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-chevron-up"></i>    
                            </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>    


    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">    

    //retorna todos os elementos com a classe .end_text
    var ends = document.querySelectorAll('.end_text');            
    var fechado = true;
    var end = 0;        

    for(var i = 0; i < ends.length; i++){
        //pega o conteudo de cada div com a classe .end_text
        end = ends[i].textContent;

        if(end.length > 120){        
            var end_novo = end.substring(0,120);        

            ends[i].parentElement.querySelector('.icone').style.display = "block";
            //oculta a div com a classe .end_text
            ends[i].style.display = "none";
            //coloca parte do texto da div com a classe .end_text na div resumo
            ends[i].parentElement.querySelector('.resumo').innerHTML = end_novo;
            ends[i].parentElement.querySelector('.resumo').style.display = "block";
        }
    }

    function fechareabrir(elemento){
        //a variavel this representa o item clicado (argunmento de fecharabrir). 
        //E tambem não é necessario alterar o conteudo da div .end_text
        //é complicado controlar o estado de varias linhas com 
        //a variavel fechado, é melhor checar o display da div resumo

        //a variavel elemento representa o elemento clicado
        //então devemos subir (acessar elementos pais) até chegar na div .end_text
        //após isso a variável elemento representa a td que possui .end_text, .resumo, .icone
        elemento = elemento.parentElement.parentElement;
        if(elemento.parentElement.querySelector(".resumo").style.display == "block"){
            abrir(elemento);
        }else{
            fechar(elemento);
        }
    }

    function abrir(elemento){

        //volta a exibir a div .end_text
        elemento.querySelector(".end_text").style.display = "block";
        //oculta a div .resumo
        elemento.querySelector(".resumo").style.display = "none";
        elemento.querySelector('.icone').style.display = "none";            
        elemento.querySelector('.icone2').style.display = "block";

    }

    function fechar(elemento){        
        //volta a exibir a div .resumo
        elemento.querySelector(".resumo").style.display = "block";

        //oculta a div .end_text
        elemento.querySelector(".end_text").style.display = "none";

        elemento.querySelector('.icone').style.display = "block";            
        elemento.querySelector('.icone2').style.display = "none";        
    }


</script>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-
Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Gerando a seguinte saida:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-
BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" 
crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-
theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-
rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" 
crossorigin="anonymous">


<body>
<style>    
.table thead tr th {
    text-align: center;
}    
.table tbody tr td{
    text-align: center;            
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.table tbody tr td.end{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px !important;        
  }            

</style>

<div class="container">

    <div class="col-md-10">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered ">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Cliente</th>
                    <th>Localidade Cliente</th>
                    <th>Cidade/UF</th>
                    <th>Endereço</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>            

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ativo</td>
                    <td >Fulano de tal</td>
                    <td>Uberlandia</td>
                    <td >Uberlandia GO</td>
                    <td class="end">    
                    <div class="end_text">
                                É um fato conhecido de todos que um leitor 
se distrairá com o conteúdo de texto legível de uma página quando estiver 
examinando sua diagramação. A vantagem de usar Lorem Ipsum é que ele tem uma 
distribuição normal de letras, ao contrário de "Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo 
aqui", fazendo com que ele tenha uma aparência similar a de um texto 
legível. Muitos softwares de publicação e editores de páginas na internet 
agora usam Lorem Ipsum como texto-modelo padrão, e uma rápida busca por ' 
lorem ipsum' mostra vários websites ainda em sua fase de construção. Várias 
versões novas surgiram ao longo dos anos, eventualmente por acidente, e às 
vezes de propósito (injetando humor, e coisas do gênero).                                    
                            </div>
                            <div class="resumo">
</div>
                            <div class="icone" style="position: 
absolute;left: 250px; top: 50px; display: none; cursor: pointer;">

                                <i onclick="fechareabrir(this)" class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>    
                            </div>    
                            <div class="icone2" style="position: 
absolute;left: 250px; bottom: 5px; display: none; cursor: pointer;">
                            
                                <i onclick="fechareabrir(this)" class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-chevron-up"></i>    
                            </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Ativo</td>
                    <td >Fulano de tal</td>
                    <td>Uberlandia</td>
                    <td >Uberlandia GO</td>
                    <td class="end">    
                    <div class="end_text">
                    É um fato conhecido de todos que um leitor 
                    se distrairá com o conteúdo de texto legível de uma página quando 
                    estiver examinando sua diagramação. A vantagem de usar Lorem Ipsum é 
                    que ele tem uma 
                    distribuição normal de letras, ao contrário de "Conteúdo aqui, conteúdo 
                    aqui", fazendo com que ele tenha uma aparência similar a de um texto 
                    legível. Muitos softwares de publicação e editores de páginas na internet 
                    agora usam Lorem Ipsum como texto-modelo padrão, e uma rápida busca por 
                    'lorem ipsum' mostra vários websites ainda em sua fase de construção. Várias 
                    versões novas surgiram ao longo dos anos, eventualmente por acidente, e às 
                    vezes de propósito (injetando humor, e coisas do gênero).                                    
                            </div>
                            <div class="resumo">
                            </div>
                            <div class="icone" style="position: 
absolute;left: 250px; top: 50px; display: none; cursor: pointer;">

                                <i onclick="fechareabrir(this)" class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-chevron-down"></i>    
                            </div>    
                            <div class="icone2" style="position: 
absolute;left: 250px; bottom: 5px; display: none; cursor: pointer;">
                            
                                <i onclick="fechareabrir(this)" class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-chevron-up"></i>    
                            </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>    


    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">    

    //retorna todos os elementos com a classe .end_text
    var ends = document.querySelectorAll('.end_text');            
    
    var end = 0;        

    for(var i = 0; i < ends.length; i++){
        //pega o conteudo de cada div com a classe .end_text
        end = ends[i].textContent;
        
        if(end.length > 120){        
            var end_novo = end.substring(0,120);        
            
            ends[i].parentElement.querySelector('.icone').style.display = "block";
            //oculta a div com a classe .end_text
            ends[i].style.display = "none";
            //coloca parte do texto da div com a classe .end_text na div resumo
            ends[i].parentElement.querySelector('.resumo').innerHTML = end_novo;
            ends[i].parentElement.querySelector('.resumo').style.display = "block";
        }
    }

    function fechareabrir(elemento){
        //a variavel this representa o item clicado (argunmento de fecharabrir). 
        //E tambem não é necessario alterar o conteudo da div .end_text
        //é complicado controlar o estado de varias linhas com 
        //a variavel fechado, é melhor checar o display da div resumo
        
        //a variavel elemento representao elemento clicado
        //então devemos subir (acessar elementos pais) até chegar na div .end_text
        //após isso a varivel elemento representa a td que possui .end_text, .resumo, .icone
        elemento = elemento.parentElement.parentElement;
        if(elemento.parentElement.querySelector(".resumo").style.display == "block"){
            abrir(elemento);
        }else{
            fechar(elemento);
        }
    }

    function abrir(elemento){
        
        //volta a exibir a div .end_text
        elemento.querySelector(".end_text").style.display = "block";
        //oculta a div .resumo
        elemento.querySelector(".resumo").style.display = "none";
        elemento.querySelector('.icone').style.display = "none";            
        elemento.querySelector('.icone2').style.display = "block";
      
    }

    function fechar(elemento){        
        //volta a exibir a div .resumo
        elemento.querySelector(".resumo").style.display = "block";
        
        //oculta a div .end_text
        elemento.querySelector(".end_text").style.display = "none";

        elemento.querySelector('.icone').style.display = "block";            
        elemento.querySelector('.icone2').style.display = "none";        
    }


</script>


<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-
Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Uma ultima coisa, arquivo bootstrap.js necessita do jquery.js ser incluido antes (mesmo que você não va utilizar). O snippet tem a inclusão (para evitar a mensagem de erro relacionada a ausencia).

Comment: Obrigado pela aula! Me ajudou muito! Obrigado!